# MenuStrip not hiding after an item is clicked. Bug?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, menustrip

I'm experiencing some really weird behavior with MenuStrip:

1. Create a new WinForms project (.net 4.0. C# or VB.NET doesn't matter; I used C#).
2. Drop a `MenuStrip` on the default form. Right-click and choose **Insert Standard Items** to quickly build it for you. This step could be done manually as well.
3. Drop a `OpenFileDialog` on your form as well.
4. Add an event handler for `DropDownItemClicked` event of the File menu. Add the following code into it:

   ```
   private void fileToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.ClickedItem.Name == "openToolStripMenuItem")
       {
           if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
               MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Run the project. Click on **File** menu and then **Open** command. The file dialog appears BUT, the **File** menu doesn't disappear. In fact it draws on top of the `OpenFileDialog`, hiding some part of it. After you click **Open** or **Cancel** in the dialog, both the dialog and the **File** menu will go away.

Why is this so? Is this a known bug or *feature*? I also checked that this doesn't happen for my dialog boxes, only for the built-in dialogs. You have to manually call `FileToolStripMenuItem.HideDropDown()` before showing built-in dialogs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug. **It's a feature**.

In fact the drop down menu will be hidden automatically after the code executing in the `DropDownItemClicked` event handler. However you use some kind of `MessageBox` or `ShowDialog` which will block the current execution and hang the drop down menu there.

There are at least 2 solutions for you to solve this, one is **hide the menu yourself before showing the Dialog** (this seems to be adopted by you). The another solution is using `BeginInvoke` to show your dialog, that `async` call won't block the current execution and the drop down menu will be hidden expectedly:

```
private void fileToolStripMenuItem_DropDownItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e){
  if (e.ClickedItem.Name == "openToolStripMenuItem")
  {
    BeginInvoke((Action)(()=>{
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
          MessageBox.Show(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    }));
  }
}
```

**NOTE**: to hide the `drop down menu` manually in the `DropDownItemClicked` event handler, you can use `e.ClickedItem.Owner.Hide()` instead of `FileToolStripMenuItem.HideDropDown()`.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for `Owner` thing. I looked around for that but was searching for `Parent` instead. The async way of doing it however doesn't appeal. This is entirely UI stuff, not a background operation, why should I put it on a different thread? In general, the framework elements raise events AFTER performing their internal state management, no? e.g. a button draws itself in released state and only then raises the `Click` event. So I can't see what purpose does this serve? Nobody would ever want to keep displaying the menu item while taking some resulting action, whether UI-based or background.

Comment: @dotNET `BeginInvoke` is not really thread, it's light-weight and used frequently to call methods `asynchronously`, you have to use it a lot when programming in `winforms` (because of such a problem like yours). I agree that such kind of implementation is a little strange. Maybe that's why they support some `Hide` method and `Visible` property for the drop down menu?

Comment: @dotNET I think there is a reason here related to `side effect`, when the `Click` actually happens, the `DropDownItemClicked` **should be fired as soon as possible** without any possibility for some code being executed in the middle. Suppose if you hide the drop down menu first, we can inject some code execution in the middle before firing the `DropDownItemClicked` event and that's even worse than the current implementation. At least with the current implementation we can fix the so-called bug easily (by 2 solutions I pointed out).

Comment: BTW, I mentioned about the `injecting some code execution in the middle` above, one of the very popular way we can inject some code here is adding some event handler for the event `VisibleChanged`, such as `fileToolStripMenuItem.VisibleChanged += (s,e) => { //much code here...//};`. If that happens, the `much code here` will be executed first before the `DropDownItemClicked` event is fired. In that case you can see some `delay` between the actual `Click` and the `Clicked` event.

Comment: OK, convinced. Kind of... ;)